# Can't listen to logs in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

On my chrome extension I'm trying to listen to logs that were output from any tab.

On my `content-script.js` I have

```
import browser from 'webextension-polyfill'

console.defaultLog = console.log.bind(console)

console.log = function () {
  console.defaultLog.apply(console, arguments)

  browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    name: 'registerLog',
    payload: { log: Array.from(arguments) }
  })
}
```

In my `background.ts` I have:

```
import browser from 'webextension-polyfill'

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(request)
})
```

Then, I created an extremely simple page `test.html` where it just has a `setInterval` using `console.log`:

```html
<html>
<script>
  setInterval(() => console.log('from page test'), 1000)
</script>
</html>
```

I can see the `from page test` log in my `test.html` but I can't see the log in my service work extension.

Is it possible to listen to `console.log`s from pages in a chrome extension? If yes, what am I doing wrong?